# Connection to SSH from external network refused

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding

I'm trying to access my Raspberry Pi via SSH from outside my home network. I've tried to set up port forwarding on my router, but so far I apparently haven't been successful.

I've set up a random port (let's say port 10001) to lead to Port 22 on my Pi. The router says the port forwarding has been successful and lists an "IPv4 address on the Internet" that is used for it. Let's call this IP address supplied by the router 100.XXX.XX.XX. This is different than the one that pops up if I go to "check my IP" sites, let's call that one 79.XXX.XXX.XXX.

I'm able to access my Pi the following ways:

- from the home network, using the Pi's internal IP (192.XXX.XXX.XX) with port 22
- from the home network, using 100.XXX.XX.XX (the "IPv4 address on the Internet" listed in the router setting) along with port "10001"
- from the home network or an external network, using the ngrok tunnelling service

I'm NOT able to access my Pi from the external network

- using 100.XXX.XX.XX with port 10001
- using 79.XXX.XXX.XXX with port 10001 or 22

Using the following combinations in Putty from the external network yields the following results:

- 79.XXX.XXX.XXX, Port 10001: Network error: Connection Refused
- 79.XXX.XXX.XXX, Port 22: Network error: Connection timed out
- 100.XXX.XX.XX, either port: Network error: Connection timed out

Remember, my external IP seems to be 79.XXX.XXX.XXX, whereas my router tells me to use 100.XXX.XX.XX (and when I'm in my home network, that one works.) My Pi is obviously listening on port 22 (I can access this from the home network) and the port forwarding has been "successful" in a way that can only be accessed from my home network. I've wondered if the Pi blocks the IP of my external network, but like I mentioned, if I setup ngrok on the Pi, that works. (I could of course just stick to ngrok, but failing at basic port forwarding seems to have become my Moby Dick.)

It's puzzling to me that the router would tell me an IP to use, which is different from the IP other sites tell me. And that this IP is actually usable from the local network but not from outside it. It strikes me as very odd.

Any tips? I'm new to this. Am I forgetting something? I don't assume the Raspbian OS would come with any pre-configured firewall.

Comment: If the WAN IP address your router's admin UI reports is different from the IP address given by "check my IP" sites, then your router is probably being given a private IP address behind a Carrier-Grade NAT (CGNAT) at your ISP. You may have to check with your ISP to find out how to make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ISP has put you behind CGNAT. Just like your home devices are behind your router's NAT and have to share a single "external" address, now your router *itself* is behind a second layer of NAT and you're sharing the "external" IP address with other customers. In other words, you do not have your own IP address anymore and cannot successfully use port forwarding without one.

(It's like stacking two routers one after another, and having to port-forward twice – only in your case there's no way to do the latter.)

> I'm NOT able to access my Pi from the external network using 100.XXX.XX.XX with port 10001

Yes, because this is actually a *private* address which is only reachable within your ISP's network.

Although not within the usual RFC1918 private ranges that everyone knows, 100.64.0.0/10 *is* in fact reserved for private use – specifically, for use by ISPs when implementing CGNAT, rather than home or corporate networks.

> I'm NOT able to access my Pi from the external network using 79.XXX.XXX.XXX with port 10001 or 22

Yes, because this address belongs to the ISP's CGNAT gateway and not to you. Because you cannot tell the ISP to set up "CGNAT port forwarding" for you, it will not relay any incoming connections to your home router.

> It's puzzling to me that the router would tell me an IP to use, which is different from the IP other sites tell me.

Well, the router correctly shows you the IP address that is assigned to the router itself. It *assumes* that this will be your "public" IP address, because this indeed used to be the case most of the time, for a very long time (until CGNAT started becoming *very* common in the last couple of years).

The router wasn't programmed to expect CGNAT, and really it doesn't know whether it is behind any kind of NAT or not. It *might* have been programmed to recognize RFC1918 private addresses where they shouldn't be, but it doesn't recognize the 100.64 range.

Although in theory the router could use an online service to check its "real" external IP address, this actually **wouldn't be useful at all.** Remember that the purpose of CGNAT is to share an address between several customers. So even if it *did* tell you the right address, nobody would be able to connect anyway – because your ISP's CGNAT gateways wouldn't know which customer is supposed to receive that connection. (As you can see whenever you're trying to connect to the 79.x.x.x address, unsuccessfully.)

So really, the router's own address is the *least wrong* option to show – whether reachable from the Internet or not, it's indeed an address which will accept the to-be-forwarded connections at least from the network that's immediately upstream.

(It's the same as when you run `ip addr` or `netstat -ltn` on the Pi and it shows you its own address.)

> And that this IP is actually usable from the local network but not from outside it. It strikes me as very odd.

The address belongs to your router. So it works internally because you're connecting directly to the router – so the packets never leave your home network. (But it doesn't work externally because it is a private range meaningless on the Internet.)

Comment: Well, that was certainly as detailed an answer as I could ever hope to get. Thank you! My Internet connection is included in my rent so I'm pretty limited. ngrok will have to suffice for now. Thanks again!